# Fetch all relationship data - Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am new to core data. I am fetching data from API and then saving them to core data.This is my dataModel.

[image]

Here is my API Structure,

```
{
"name" : "name here",
"content" :[
{
    "homeContentItems" : [
    {
         "some objects" : "values",
         "contentItemDetails": [
          {
          }, 
          {
          }
         ]
    },
    {
         "some objects" : "values",
         "contentItemDetails": [
          {
          }, 
          {
          }
         ]
    }

  ]
},
{
    "homeContentItems" : [
    {
         "some objects" : "values",
         "contentItemDetails": [
          {
          }, 
          {
          }
         ]
    },
    {
         "some objects" : "values",
         "contentItemDetails": [
          {
          }, 
          {
          }
         ]
    }

  ]
}

]
}
```

How can I fetch data from the Entity so I can get all data from related entity too?

I Have never worked with database before so its bit complected for me. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
let informedDataFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Informed360Entity")
    informedDataFetch.fetchLimit = 1
    informedDataFetch.predicate = NSPredicate()
    let tableviewData = try! context.fetch(informedDataFetch)

    let tdata : Informed360Entity = tableviewData.first as! Informed360Entity
    var contentData = tdata.toContent?.allObjects as? [ContentEntity]
```

I tried this code and getting data from ContentEntity table. How can I get other 2 tables data too so I can use to display in tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it the same way as you did with ContentEntity but now you use the two properties that represent the relationships, `contentDetailItem` and `homeContentItems`, which both will return a Set.

```
 for content in contentData {
     let contentDetailItems = content.contentDetailItem
     let homeContents = content.homeContentItems
     //...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much friend!! It was that easy and I was struggling all day. Thanks agin!!